# How to customize labels in TreePlot?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, labeling, trees

I want to specify the labels attached to vertices in `TreePlot`, allowing distinct vertices to carry the same label. The following attempt fails:

```
aTree =   TreeGraph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3}, VertexLabels -> {1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 3 -> "b"}]; 
TreePlot[aTree, VertexLabeling -> True]
```

and so does

```
aTree = TreeGraph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3},  VertexLabels -> {1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 3 -> "b"}]; 
TreePlot[ Rule @@@ EdgeList[aTree], DirectedEdges -> True,  VertexLabeling -> True]
```

Any idea?

Comment: Why are you using `TreePlot` when you already have the correct layout from `TreeGraph`?  You can just re-style the TreeGraph using EdgeStyle, VertexStyle, Placed in VertexLabels, VertexShapeFunction, etc.  See the documentation for each of these.

Comment: The reason is that I'm fully happy with the layout produced by TreePlot, except for the fact it does not allow identical labels for different vertices.

Comment: Sounds like all you need is TreeGraph then, as it produces the same layout as TreePlot.  TreePlot and GraphPlot are old functions from before Mathematica has a Graph data structure.  They are fully replaced by newer constructs.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify PlotTheme in TreeGraph

```
TreeGraph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3}, 
 VertexLabels -> 
  Thread[{1, 2, 3} -> (Placed[#, Center] & /@ {"a", "b", "b"})], 
 PlotTheme -> "VintageDiagram"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have switched to TreeGraph and got it to work.

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2:** Came across a *hidden* option `"VertexNames"` for `TreePlot`

```
TreePlot[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3}, 
  VertexLabeling -> True, 
 "VertexNames" -> {"A", "B", "B"}]
```

[image]

This also works for  `GraphPlot` and `LayeredGraphPlot`.

**Note:** In versions 12.0, `TreePlot` is changed substantially, and the legacy `Treeplot` is available under the name `` GraphComputation`TreePlotLegacy ``.

**Update:** If you have to use `TreePlot` you can  post-process the output of `TreePlot` to relabel the vertices.

The function `reLabelF` below takes a list of vertices to be relabeled (`vertices`)  and their new labels(`labels`) and post-processes a `TreePlot` output (`tp`) to get a relabeled `TreePlot`:

```
ClearAll[reLabelF]
reLabelF[verts_, labels_][tp_] := tp /. (Framed[#, p__] :> Framed[#2, p] & @@@ 
    Transpose[{verts, labels}])
```

Examples:

```
vertices = {1, 2, 3};
labels =  Style[#, 18, "Panel"] & /@ {"a", "b", "b"};

TreePlot[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3}, VertexLabeling -> True] // reLabelF[vertices, labels]
```

[image]

Relabel only the vertices `{1, 2, 3}`:

```
 TreePlot[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 1 -> 4, 2 -> 5}, VertexLabeling -> True] // 
   reLabelF[vertices, labels]
```

[image]

Relabel all vertices:

```
TreePlot[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 1 -> 4, 2 -> 5}, VertexLabeling -> True] // 
 reLabelF[Range[5], Style[#, 18, "Panel"] & /@ {"a", "b", "b", "b", "c"}]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

You can specify the labels for each vertex using `Property` and use the built-in `"VintageDiagram"` for `GraphStyle` option setting:

```
labeledvertices = Property[#, VertexLabels -> 
  Placed[Style[#2, 18, "Panel", Background -> Transparent], Center]] & @@@
    Transpose[{{1, 2, 3}, {"a", "b", "b"}}];

TreeGraph[labeledvertices, {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3}, GraphStyle -> "VintageDiagram"]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use a different built-in `GraphStyle`:

```
TreeGraph[labeledvertices, {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3},  GraphStyle -> "DiagramGold"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
rule = {1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 3 -> "b"};
shapeRule = Rule[#1, Text[Style[#2, Black, "Text"]]] & @@@ rule;
aTree = TreeGraph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3}, VertexShape -> shapeRule, 
  VertexSize -> Large]
```

Out:

[image: Mathematica graphics]